# Highcharts (highstock) plotting incorrect date on x-axis line chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here I have an example of a highstock chart I have generated: http://jsfiddle.net/9gTN8/

There are 3 data points with dates defined using the `Date.UTC` method. Despite the last date in the series being `2013-07-15`, the point is plotted in August. Likewise the other points appear to be  being plotted a month ahead of where they should be.

I have used `ordinal: false` to allow for irregular date intervals, which is a feature of highstock.

What is the reason for this and how can I solve it?

Edit:

My date in each datapoint is produced from php like so:

```
echo "\n[Date.UTC(" . date("Y, m, d", strtotime($date)) . "), " . $value . "]";
```

I know I could have several php `date()` functions to decrement the month myself but I'd hope there'd be a more efficient way. E.g. is it possible to replicate the javascript `Date.UTC` method in php and just output the big number (no. of milliseconds since 01/01/1970) straight off?

Comment: Months in Date.UTC() are indexed from 0, not 1.

Comment: OK, at them moment the date is generated as shown in my edit. What's the most efficient way to produce the correct date?

Comment: Which dates should be ?

Comment: IMO the best way to generate the date is to not use Date.UTC at all, and to send en epoch timestamp.  Otherwise, you just need to isolate the month number and subtract 1 from it...

Comment: Yes, that was my thought. How to make the epoch timestamp though? PHP appears not to have a `Date.UTC` method like that of JS...

Comment: or maybe it does.... will `time()` do the trick?

Comment: Solved! `1000 * date("U", strtotime($date))` does it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to not use `Date.UTC` and just use php's date format like so:

```
echo "\n[" . 1000 * date("U", strtotime($date)) . ", " . $value . "]";
```

This will output the epoch timestamp as defined in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) in seconds. Times by 1000 to get milliseconds as javaScript requires.